# Temasys howto alter existing code

Tags: javascript, webrtc, polyfills

I have this piece of code in place that eventually passes the constraints to getUserMedia.

```
function captureUserMedia(callback) {
$('#videoSource').css('display', 'none');
var videoSource = videoSelect.value;
var constraints = null;

constraints = {
    video: {

        optional: [{
            sourceId: videoSource
        }]
    },
    audio: false
}


var htmlElement = document.getElementById('rtcvideo');
htmlElement.setAttribute('autoplay', true);
htmlElement.setAttribute('controls', true);

var mediaConfig = {
    video: htmlElement,
    onsuccess: function(stream) {
        config.attachStream = stream;
        callback && callback();
        htmlElement.setAttribute('muted', true);
        rotateInCircle(htmlElement);
    },


    onerror: function() {
        alert('unable to get access to your webcam');
    }
};
if (constraints) mediaConfig.constraints = constraints;
getUserMedia(mediaConfig);
streamAttached = true;
}
```

I.ve tried numerous things to get it working and the difficulty perhaps lies in the callback which i found hard to get my head around.
How can i alter this piece of code so it'll work?
I've tried to precede getUsermedia with navigator but it needs 3 parameters from which two are the succes and error callbacks.
I can see the onerror and onsucces calbacks in the mediaconfig var.
Can someone please take a look at it?

***update***

I just saw that getUserMedia is a function defined in an attached RTCPeerConnection-v1.5.js file:

```
function getUserMedia(options) {
var n = navigator,
    media;
n.getMedia = n.webkitGetUserMedia || n.mozGetUserMedia;
n.getMedia(options.constraints || {
        audio: true,
        video: video_constraints
    }, streaming, options.onerror || function(e) {
        console.error(e);
    });

function streaming(stream) {
    var video = options.video;
    if (video) {
        video[moz ? 'mozSrcObject' : 'src'] = moz ? stream : window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        video.play();
    }
    options.onsuccess && options.onsuccess(stream);
    media = stream;
}

return media;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have more code around that. (videoSelect.value won't work with videoSelect undefined)

If you check [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/mediacapture-streams/#widl-NavigatorUserMedia-getUserMedia-void-MediaStreamConstraints-constraints-NavigatorUserMediaSuccessCallback-successCallback-NavigatorUserMediaErrorCallback-errorCallback), the constraints and callbacks are 3 separate arguments.
it should look like:

```
getUserMedia(mediaConfig.constraints, mediaConfig.onsuccess, mediaConfig.onerror);
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: I just updated the question. I wasn't aware of the fact that getUserMedia was defined as a function in an attached js file. Isn't it a reserved word? But perhaps it's more clear now?